# How to get the number of inserts from a raw INSERT query in Django?

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, orm

I'm running a fairly large `insert into select` query in Django, which I do using

```
MyModel.objects.raw(insert_query)
```

But that doesn't do anything since queries seem to only be run when something is taken from it's result. So when I do this it runs the query

```
MyModel.objects.raw(insert_query)[0]
```

but also gives an error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I can run the queries using

```
from django.db import connection
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(insert_query)
```

But that doesn't give me any feedback on what it actually did.

Is there a way that I can run the raw query and get the number of records it inserted or a possible error if that occurred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get number of records added through

```
cursor.rowcount
```